# Does android reuse images loaded from resource?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-resources

So I have several ImageViews in a single Activity and all of them use the same image bitmap from a resource.

```
ImageViewOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.frequently_used_image);
ImageViewTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.frequently_used_image);
ImageViewThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.frequently_used_image);
```

Does android allocate memory to load the bitmap once and reuse it for all other ImageViews using the same resource? Or does it load the bitmap **each time** it is set to an ImageView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting Dianne Hackborn from Android team:

> Also keep in mind that Resources already maintains a cache of Drawables for you, using this facility, so there is no need for you to implement your own cache for any Drawables you are retrieving from Resources.

from this answer: [Consequences of drawable.setCallback(null);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648740/consequences-of-drawable-setcallbacknull/7692784#7692784)

Comment: Does that mean if my app has a ton of drawable files, it's going to be using memory even if I never use them on my app?

Comment: @baekacaek No. The cache is an "intelligent" being. It keeps only images that are used and drops them when memory is needed.