# Does Android reuse Bitmaps loaded from resources?

Tags: android, bitmap

In my app, I often use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`, like so:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_name);
```

The question is: if I create several Bitmaps from the same image resource, will Android point them to the same location in memory?

(I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098755/does-android-reuse-images-loaded-from-resource) question, but it is about `Drawables`).

Comment: This is easy to test: create several bitmaps. In the debugger, see if they have matching pointers.