# When 2 ImageViews are declared in xml layout then there are 2 copies of drawable in memory?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-bitmap, android-memory

When I have an xml layout like:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image" />
```

Then there are 2 instances of the bitmap associated with drawable in memory or just one?

Comment: If you will change `drawable` tint color programmatically, then load same `drawable` resource form another screen - the `drawable` tint will be as you defined programmatically, so i guess it is cached

Comment: The below are the link that might be helpful. [Does android reuse images loaded from resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098755/does-android-reuse-images-loaded-from-resource) [Consequences of drawable.setCallback(null);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648740/consequences-of-drawable-setcallbacknull/7692784#7692784)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what @tynn answer refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer here :

For instance, every time you create a Button, a new drawable is loaded from the framework resources (android.R.drawable.btn_default). This means all buttons across all the apps use a different drawable instance as their background. However, all these drawables share a common state, called the "constant state."

source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html?m=1

Comment: that's super helpful blog post!

Comment: @MarianPaździoch, please upvote the answer if you found it useful in the context.

Answer (score 3):

When loading drawables from `Resources`, these will be cached with a `DrawableCache` which is a `ThemedResourceCache`.

The `ResourcesImpl` [states in a comment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a09e9e4fe112a9db923cfee520ed7acfd708ecdc/core/java/android/content/res/ResourcesImpl.java#622):

> ```
> // First, check whether we have a cached version of this drawable
> // that was inflated against the specified theme. Skip the cache if
> // we're currently preloading or we're not using the cache.
> ```

Comment: Could you link to the source of that?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch I added the link to the google source.

Comment: Do you know how this caching refers to what Abhisek Mallick answered below?

Comment: I'd assume the cache is actually mostly handling the state. Drawables are mutable structures and thus caching the whole object might be more problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!!!

I have viewed source code and it looks like it will create new bitmap instances for each ImageView. There is a cumbersome process goes under all of that...

ImageView uses Drawable

Drawable uses ImageDecoder

ImageDecoder uses BitmapFactory

BitmapFactory uses [native C++ code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7b2f8b8/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.cpp) for image decoding. (Look at line 157 and below)

Brief look at the code tells me that it will create new instances of <s>bitmap</s> Drawable for each ImageView even if used same image. I didn't find any logic related to such optimization.

**UPDATE**

Yes there is a optimization took place in case of bitmap loading. Abhisek Mallick absolutely right. Even without looking into the code it is easy to check. Create a RecyclerView with ImageView's. Load into those ImageView's same bitmap. And try to change the number of items. While changing look at the Profiler->Memory. Memory allocation won't be changed.

Comment: Take a look at Abhisek Mallick and tynn answers - I think your is not valid.